# How to earn smooth scroll (not to anchors)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw some sites (Apple have some effects where they earned it [after exceptional materials title](https://www.apple.com/iphone-xs/)), where a simple scroll moves elements not like jumping, but with transition. I also earned this effect with transition, but

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("p");
window.onscroll = () => {
  const wT = window.pageYOffset;
  elem.style.transform = `translateY(-${wT}px)`
}
```

```css
p {
  margin: 20vw;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat. Vestibulum rhoncus
  est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis. Semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin gravida. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae. Viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat.
  Sodales neque sodales ut etiam. A condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. Lectus arcu bibendum at varius. Egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit
  laoreet. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum. Placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam. Risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam. Nisi porta
  lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a. Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar. Enim nec dui nunc mattis enim. Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac. Eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas
  diam. Pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor. Pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie
  at elementum eu facilisis. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec. Vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus. Adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat
  in fermentum. Justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin. Adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim.</p>
```

as you can see, it's like two phases, and not so smooth even if you scroll faster or change scroll directions fast. Do you have any idea how can I earn the smooth effect as it shown the above link?

Comment: What do you mean by "earn"?

Comment: Retrieve make create